# AS3, Flash - Function to go to label?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was thinking of making a function which can be called and will send to the called label..

Well, I currently do this for all buttons:

```
myButtonSomething.addEventListener(Event, GoToLabelSomething);

function GoToLabelSomething (e:Event):void{
   this.gotoAndStop("Something");
}
```

Would it not be possible to do so that.. Like in PHP it would be this:

```
GoToLabel("something");

function GoToLabel($label) {
  // gotoAndStop($label); or something....
}
```

I hope I make sense :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this :

```
var labelName:String = "something";
myButtonSomething.addEventListener(Event, function(e:Event){
    GoToLabel(labelName);
});

function GoToLabel (name:String):void{
   this.gotoAndStop(name);
}
```